# Jupyter Notebook Azure Machine Learning Experiment

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

The following code is provided by my Azure Machine Learning workspace. I have two errors in the output panes.

[Jupyter Notebook ML Experiment](https://europewest.notebooks.azureml.net/n/om0ncnpgsxd7aq/notebooks/Run%20result%209-14-2018%201_15_27%20PM%20Python%203%20notebook.ipynb)

The first is a Value Error which appears to be unable to recognize my 'Workspace ID' authorization token after running the code in Cell 1. Does this mean Microsoft Azure is failing to recognize my 'Workspace ID' even though I performed the whole experiment?

The second error is a Name Error which fails to run the 'frame' code in cell 2. The 'frame' variable is defined in the code in Cell 1 as: frame = ds.to_dataframe() so why does the error message say **'frame' is not defined?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not being able to check your Notebook. I think you should try to paste some image or instead write the code snippet directly in your post.

Independently of this, the best way to access your workspace from a Notebook or a local IDE is by using the 'Generate Data Access Code...', option in the context menu available at the output node of the modules. By clicking here you will see the code (in Python and R) necessary to copy/paste in your Notebook to access correctly to datasets or intermediate data in your experiment, in other words, your whole workspace.

If the 'Generate...' option appears disabled, drag to your canvas a 'Convert to CSV' module and connect the output which you are interested in to the input of this module. Run the experiment and click on the 'Generate...' option that will be now enabled at the output of the 'Convert...' module. See the images below to have an idea. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: My apologies for removing access to the Azure ML notebook link. I cancelled my Azure subscription for the ML service and Microsoft removed the notebook which is why you can no longer view it. Having said that, your tip to 'Generate a Data Access Code' is extremely useful. Thank you!